# Caliburn.Micro injecting a Collection with Xamarin.Forms Application

Tags: xamarin.forms, caliburn.micro

I am using **Caliburn.Micro** in combination with **Xamarin.Forms**. Within my App class, I register an interface ILicenseInfo with a class LicenseInfoImplementation via the SimpleContainer's PerRequest method. 
CM then injects an object when my view model is created (see ViewModelOne) which is what I want. However, I don't see how I can extend this to a collection of objects. Lets say I would like CM to instantiate ViewModelTwo which expects a collection of object. How would I have to change App.cs and the XAML of ViewModelTwo to make that happen?

```
public partial class App : FormsApplication
{
    private readonly SimpleContainer _container;

    public App (SimpleContainer container)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._container = container;    
        // register interface and class
        _container.PerRequest<ILicenseInfo, LicenseInfoImplementation>();   
        //....
    }
}

public ViewModelOne(ILicenseInfo license)
{
    // Great, Caliburn.Micro injects an LicenseInfoImplementation object
}

public ViewModelTwo(IEnumerable<ILicenseInfo> licenses)
{
    // No idea 
}
```

Comment: What about writing a wrapper, so you would write an interface `ILicenseInfoContainer` with property IEnumerable<LicenseInfo> do your implementation of that, register it in your CM container and use it in your viewModel

Comment: That would be a doable workaround. Another one would be to create a default constructor and within it retrieve the desired collection via IEnumberable<ILicenseInfo> impl = IoC.Get<ILicenseInfo>(); Ideally, I am looking for a solution where I do not have to change the signatures of my view model methods or create an explicit CM dependency (like using the IoC class in the view model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used the following pattern. Not the most elegant way to do it but the best I found ...

```
public ViewModelTwo() : base (IoC.GetAll<ILicenseInfo>())
{
}

public ViewModelTwo(IEnumerable<ILicenseInfo> licenses)
{
// Do something with licenses
}
```